# rendering html.erb file that was prepaired for rendering javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I dont know how best to describe my problem, so I will try with example:
I have got in my controller

my res.js.erb is like this:

```
$ ( document).ready(function(){
$("#prikazuj").html('<%= render "rest"%>');
$('#res_').focus();
});
```

and I have in _rest.html.erb:

```
<%= t(:Measurementn) %>:<%= @measure.measurment %><br>\
<%= t(:player) %>:<%= @playerr.name %><br>\
```

In _rest.html.erb I have \ so that javascript can interpret this html correctly.
But now, if I want to use same <%= render "rest"%> in any other view, I got bunch of \ characters...
What is the best way to get rid of them? I know I can make rest.html.erb in one line, but I then it is unreadable later...
Thank you
Dorijan

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the javascript when calling the partial from the javascript code and let the `rest` partial as *normal*.

```
$("#prikazuj").html('<%= escape_javascript(render("rest")) %>');
```